# Prestashop - Module, SEO & URL and parameters?

Tags: seo, prestashop

I made a module for Prestashop that will display content based on the given ID in parameter (&id=X).

I'd like to set a nice url for this module.

Using SEO and URLS, I see that it's possible, but it keeps the ?id=X in the url.

For example, if I define the url to my module to be

```
/pretty-module
```

I will have the same links but with the different id :

```
/pretty-module?id=1
/pretty-module?id=23
```

What I'd like to do, is the following :

```
/pretty-module => will set id to 1
/even-prettier-module => will set id to 23
```

I didn't saw a "parameters" options in the SEO & URLS page in the Backoffice, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do this.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in PS but you could write your own override have look here https://github.com/Ha99y/prestashopCleanURLs

Comment: Thansk but it seems heavy (overriding a lot of prestashop), just for that. I think settings an htaccess will be simpler (it's for a specific use case, I was hoping to find something easy, in general.

Comment: You should set it in your own module, I mean, the module should override the modules used for URL handling, you should create a configuration page, where you define "which URL is which ID".

Comment: Do you have a link to a free module or a tutorial on how to do this ? I would be interested :)

Answer (score 8):

you need to hook to moduleRoutes,

1) in your module install method:

```
if (!parent::install()           
    || !$this->registerHook('moduleRoutes')
    || !$this->registerHook('displayFooter'))
       return false;
```

2) creating corresponding hook

```
public function hookmoduleRoutes($params) {
    $routes = array();
    $routes['module-examplemodule-handler'] = array(
        'controller'=>'handler',
        'rule'=>'promo{/:code}',
        'keywords'=>array(
            'code'=>array(
                'regexp'=>'[\w]+',
                'param'=>'short_code'
            )
        ),
        'params'=>array(
            'fc'=>'module',
            'module'=>'examplemodule',
            'controller'=>'handler'
        )
    );

    return $routes;
}
```

module may have multi routes.
 the convention is *module-[MODULE_NAME]-[MODULE_CONTROLLER_NAME]*

array explanation:

controller - *handler* (modules/examplemodule/controllers/front/handler.php)

rule - curly braces are params.. you can get an idea from http://example.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminMeta

keywords - here you configure your params (curly braces) defined in the rule.

usage example: http://example.com/promo/ADSGD

in controller 'handler':

```
$short_code = Tools::getValue('short_code');
```

**tested on prestashop 1.6**

reference: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=BsSiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=prestashop+module+Routes+hook&source=bl&ots=JCb_4oz6el&sig=JwoQfIsOnJ49VJ752fEb01ivMZ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vH0QVePiDoXPaNSxgrAP&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=prestashop%20module%20Routes%20hook&f=false

Comment: This link is not available, I have to pay for it. This is not accepted in Stackoverflow. Please either provide a valid, free, link or copy/paste the solution here.

Comment: @CyrilN. I posted example and explanation

Comment: Great, I switched from -1 to +1. You can put the link to the book back, it's not a problem as long as the answer can be accessed for free (in StackOverflow) (good thing if you are the author of the book).

Comment: I can't test right now but once I'll be able, I'll come back to mark your answer as accepted if it's fix my issue :)

Comment: ok, thank you, Im not an author of the book.. :)
hope it will work for you!

Comment: @salexch where is the hook documented though? O.o I only found forums and bug-reports x)

Comment: For this to work, you have to remove any existing SEO&URL records for your module's controller in backoffice/admin :)