# Prestashop 1.6 - Create front end page in custom module

Tags: php, module, overriding, prestashop-1.6

I currently works on a custom module who add features to the Prestashop native store locator.

For my needs, i must create a second custom page in my module (and a second controller).

I tried something but nothing works.

I override FrontController file in my directory -> /module/override/controllers/front/StorepageController.php

```
<?php

class StorepageController extends FrontController
{

    public function initContent()
    {
      parent::initContent();

      $this->setTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'modulename/views/templates/front/storepage.tpl');
    }
```

And i put my .tpl file in this directory -> /module/views/templates/front/storepage.tpl

And to finish, i erase "class_index.php" and i try to see my page with this link :

localhost/prestashop/fr/index.php?controller=storepage

I don't understand why nothing is working.

Comment: When you say nothing is working, what's happening exactly?

Comment: If I remember right you overrided the default StoresController.php in a previous question. Is this override working? Here your are trying to create a second controller but you're using override syntax. I'll post an example of module controller creation as an answer.

Comment: Hi,

An error 404 page appear when i try to access to this custom controller.

And yes, it's another Controller that i want to create. 
My Custom StoresController works perfectly.

Here, I want to create a customized page that displays some information from my StoresController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we will create a new Controller called `myStore` in a module called `CustomStores`. We will take into account that you already overrided the default `StoresController.php`.

Your module looks like this:

```
/customstores
    /customstores.php
    /config.xml
    /override
        /controllers
            /front
                StoresController.php
    /views
        /templates
            /front
                /stores.tpl
```

Now you want to had a new controller, it's not an override. we will create this new Controller by extending the `ModuleFrontController`.

Your module tree will now look like this:

```
/customstores
    /customstores.php
    /config.xml
    /override
        /controllers
            /front
                StoresController.php
    /views
        /templates
            /front
                /stores.tpl
                /mystore.tpl
    /controllers
        /front
            /mystore.php
    /classes
        /CustomStore.php
```

Following is `mystore.php` code:

```
<?php

include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'customstores/classes/CustomStore.php');

/**
 * the name of the class should be [ModuleName][ControllerName]ModuleFrontController
 */
class CustomStoresMyStoreModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->ssl = false;
    }

    /**
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        // We will consider that your controller possesses a form and an ajax call

        if (Tools::isSubmit('storeAjax'))
        {
            return $this->displayAjax();
        }

        if (Tools::isSubmit('storeForm'))
        {
            return $this->processStoreForm();
        }

        $this->getContent();
    }

    public function getContent($assign = true)
    {
        $content = array('store' => null, 'errors' => $errors);

        if (Tools::getValue('id_store') !== false)
        {
            $content['store'] = new CustomStore((int) Tools::getValue('id_store'));

            if (! Validate::isLoadedObject($content['store']))
            {
                $content['store'] = null;
                $content['errors'][] = "Can't load the store";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $content['errors'][] = "Not a valid id_store";
        }


        if ($assign)
        {
            $this->context->smarty->assign($content);
        }
        else
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }

    public function displayAjax()
    {
        return Tools::jsonEncode($this->getContent(false));
    }

    public function processStoreForm()
    {
        // Here you get your values from the controller form
        $like = Tools::getValue('like');
        $id_store = (int) Tools::getValue('id_store');
        // And process it...
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'formResult' = CustomStore::like($id_store, $like)
        ));

        // And finally display the page
        $this->getcontent();
    }
}
```

I've also added a custom class for you module called `CustomStore.php`, here we go for the code:

```
<?php

class CustomStore extends ObjectModel
{
    public $id_custom_store;

    public $name;

    public $nb_likes;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'customstores_store',
        'primary' => 'id_custom_store',
        'fields' => array(
            'name' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
            'nb_likes' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        ),
    );

    public static function like($id_store, $like)
    {
        $store = new CustomStore($id_store);

        if (! Validate::isLoadedObject($store))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (! ($like == 1 || $like == -1))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $store->nb_likes + (int) $like;
        $store->save();
    }
}
```

You will have to create the `customstores_store` table inside your module `install()` method:

```
DB::getInstance()->execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "customstores_store` (
      `id_custom_store` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
      `nb_likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_custom_store`)
    ) ENGINE=" . _MYSQL_ENGINE_ . " DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"
);
```

---

This code was not tested and was written in a single shot, but all the concept you will need are here ;). I advise you to look at other core modules code if you want to learn more. Have fun !

Comment: Few minutes ago, I found documentation that made ​​me understand my mistake.
And you confirm this mistake. 

Your CustomStore is just an example on how call and use a custom class in my module controller ?   thanks you again for your help !

Comment: Yes it is. I should add that you can access your controller using this url: `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?fc=module&module=customstores&controller=mystore&id_store=1` you can define a friendly URL in backoffice in `SEO` section.

Comment: I think i must manipulate and understand the pretashop core to code with more facility. 
I begin to assimilate and thank you for your great help.

Comment: Hello - I have created a custom page in my module and I have given it a friendly URL. I can now visit my module page by going to `myshop.com/module-page-url`. Do you know how I can make this dynamic? For example: `myshop.com/module-page-url/param1`? I want to pass parameters to the module page controller using a friendly URL. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659444/prestashop-module-seo-url-and-parameters)

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre in your code you didn't display the tpl files stores.tpl
  and mystore.tpl, you should call one of them in getContent function