# How to use translate fuction in prestashop module

Tags: module, prestashop, translation

We want to use translate function for our module in prestashop ($this->l()) 
We can use this function from Main Class of module but when we wanted to use it from external files of module we ran into trouble.

On external page we use

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/settings.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../classes/Cookie.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');
$context = Context::getContext();
```

but when we use $context->l() we get error so how can we use translate in our external file of our module ?

thank you

Comment: Can't you use module front controller to do the same thing as does files? It's the correct way. There you have more options/possibilities. Also, then you could use smarty for the templates.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you !

Comment: For more on how to create a modulefrontcrontroler, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528660/prestashop-1-6-create-front-end-page-in-custom-module